# Excel 2010 Pivot Table Column Headings from SQL bit field

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, bit-fields

I have a bit field in my SQL Server data table called 'inPub' with 1/0 True/False values.

When I surface the data in an Excel pivot table I get a layout like this 
[image: Pivot Table headings]

How do nI change those TRUE/FALSE display values into something more meaningful and insightful such as InPub/NotInPub

Comment: Create a separate table with the actual description and join them. You can also use a `CASE WHEN` to replace values with text but that would mean you'd have to change the query each time you wanted to change the text

Comment: PS: I assume you don't* actually mean `bitfield`, ie a field where each individual bit represents a different flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could choose to overwrite the value's in the pivottable just by typing over them.

Nicer would be to put a view on you table in SQL server used for reporting (second layour on base data)

Comment: Thats the simplest and most useful answer to me